# SQL Server runs SP on startup - where's the magic?

Tags: sql

We have several **SQL Server 2008 R2** environments **(dev, QA, Production)** with databases for an **ASP.NET** application.

This applicaton uses **ASP.NET membership** and **SQL Server session providers**, thus we have an **ASPState database**.

The functionality of these providers were extended to restrict one active session per login.  Our implementation added tables to **TempDB**, a stored `proc ASPState.dbo.CreateTempTables` to create these tables, and another stored `proc Master.dbo.ASPState_Startup` which calls the **SP** in **ASPState**.

On my dev machine and in production, when **SQL Server** is started `Master.dbo.ASPState_Startup` is executed and the tables are created.

I am setting up a new **QA environment** and cannot figure out how that happens (so in **QA**, the tables are not added to **TempDB** on **startup**).  I have compared schema and permissions manually and via **Red Gate's compare tool** and find no differences there.

I checked the jobs and none call either of these stored procs.

Any ideas of where the magic is hiding?

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`sp_procoption`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181720.aspx) is the "magic":

> Sets or clears a stored procedure for automatic execution. A stored procedure that is set to automatic execution runs every time an instance of SQL Server is started.

```
EXEC sp_procoption @ProcName = 'ASPState_Startup' 
, @OptionName = 'startup' 
, @OptionValue = 'on';
```

Comment: Thank you.  I learned that I can see that property by selecting to "Script Stored procedure as" > "Create" (instead of "Modify" which is my usual habit.